# JQuery get closest div above element with class

Tags: jquery

I am looping through all `h1` elements and looking for the closest div with a class of `box-body`

```
$('h1').each(function(index, element) {
    if($(this).attr("id")) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $( '#' + id ).text( data[id] );

        $( this ).closest( "box-body" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
    }
});
```

I tried using `$( this ).closest( "box-body" )` and setting the CSS, but its not setting it.

the `h1` tags are in HTML as follows, so this is what it loop through and where the `box-body` is located

```
<section class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box no-border">
    <div class="box-body">
        <h1 id="rmm_num_servers">-</h1>
        <h4>RMM Total Servers</h4>
    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</section><!-- /.col -->

<section class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box no-border">
    <div class="box-body">
        <h1 id="rmm_num_ws">-</h1>
        h4>RMM Total Workstations</h4>
    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</section><!-- /.col -->
```

Comment: what is `box-body` ???. If id use `#` and for class use `.`

Comment: @Shree see my update

Comment: `box-body` is class so use `.`  Eg: `closest( ".box-body" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As box-body is a class use a `.` to identify it with class name

```
$( this ).closest( ".box-body" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: why is this downvoted? it will get the closest parent element that matches a selector. Also you can use `.parent()` and check if it matches `.box-body`. there is usually more than 1 way.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) : For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

In your case you also need to search for all [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and their [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) too.
I think this suits you better:

$(this).parents().siblings("div.box-body").css( "background-color", "red" );